# Linked Lists to strings in C

Tags: c

given a single linked list which has two digits in each node, convert that to a string (first node has msb). example 12->34->56->78 should output as "12345678"
Please give me answer how to code the above problem.

This is the code (copied from OP comment), which is going wrong with the `j` indices.

```
i = 0; 
j = 0; 
temp1 = head; 
while (temp1 != NULL) { 
    num = temp1->data; 
    i = i++; 
    j = i+2; 
    while (num != 0) { 
        ct = num % 10; 
        num = num / 10; 
        r[j-2] = ct+'0'; 
        j--;
    } 
    r[i+1] = ',';
    temp1 = temp1->ptr;
}
r[i-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Just print all node in a single line.

Comment: On stackoverflow.com, it's expected that you will work on your problem and show what you've done and where you're stuck.

Comment: I should return the value to the main function@haccks

Comment: i = 0; j = 0;
 temp1 = head;
 while (temp1 != NULL)
 {
  num = temp1->data;
  i = i++;
  j = i+2;
  while (num != 0)
  {
   ct = num % 10;
   num = num / 10;
   r[j-2] = ct+'0';
   j--;
  }
  r[i+1] = ',';
  temp1 = temp1->ptr;
 }
 r[i-1] = '\0';
This is going wrong with the j indices..@Simon Gibbons

Comment: Update your question please.

Comment: An `int` and `for` loop (or a `while` loop), `stdio.h`, and `printf`.

Comment: `i = i++;` is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: use sprintf() to get number in a character array

Answer (score 0):

C has got some great tools. You can directly get the data in string using sprintf() so no need to slice the number into individual digits.

```
temp1 = head;
char c[3];
char r[MAX]="";
while (temp1 != NULL)
{
    num = temp1->data;
    sprintf(c,"%d",num);
    //printf("%s\n",c);
    strcat(r,c);
    temp1 = temp1->ptr;
}
printf("%s\n",r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of indexing has led to trouble because it is too complicated and hard to follow. Only one index is necessary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLEN 100

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *ptr;
} node;

node* add_node(node *root, int id) {
    // Add a node to the list with begins at root, return new root
    node *n = malloc( sizeof (node) );
    if (n == NULL) {
        printf("Fatal Error: Out of memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    n->data = id;
    n->ptr = root;
    return n;
}

void free_list(node *root) {
    // free the list which starts with root
    node *tmp;
    while (root) {
        tmp = root->ptr;    
        free(root);
        root = tmp;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    node *temp1, *head = NULL;
    char r[MAXLEN+1] = "";
    int i = 0;
    head = add_node(head, 78);
    head = add_node(head, 56);
    head = add_node(head, 34);
    head = add_node(head, 12);

    temp1 = head; 
    while (temp1 != NULL) {
        if (i+2 > MAXLEN) {
            printf ("Out of string space!\n");
            break;
        }
        r[i++] = '0' + temp1->data / 10;
        r[i++] = '0' + temp1->data % 10;
        r[i] = 0;
        temp1 = temp1->ptr;
    }
    printf ("%s\n", r);

    free_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
12345678
```